# How to call Class of one dll to another dll in c# within the same project solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have one class in Project Proj1 and i want to access it into another Project Proj2.Both the project are in same solution .How can i do it .Thanks in advance

Comment: Add reference of Proj1 into Proj2

Comment: @ManishParakhiya, post it as answer probably with little more explanation.

Comment: Actually here the problem of circular dependancy @ManishParakhiya

Comment: That is because you probably add reference into each other project. You must reference in single direction

Comment: @MayankChoudhary Damn it, that's a different problem altogether. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427696/c-sharp-accessing-a-class-from-a-parent-project-in-a-child-project/28427844#28427844

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a project reference from Project 2 to project 1, like so:

1. Right-click on "References" in Project 2

[image]

2. Add reference...

[image]

3. Solution | Projects

[image]

4. Tick Project 1 (In my case I've got a project called "library" but the same applies)

[image]

And then hit Ok. This allows you access to your class, and every other class in your referenced project, as long as the access modifiers allow you to.